# How to create and access environment variable in WSO2 siddi file?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, stream-processing, wso2-streaming-integrator

I tried to export variable inside the WSO2 container. but when I'm trying to retrieve it in siddhi file it is returning null. I'm able to get data for predefined environment variables HOME, PATH etc

```
@sink(type='log')
define stream KeyStream (key string);

@sink(type='log', prefix='Sweet Totals:')
define stream OutputStream(FunctionOutput string);


@info(name='SweetTotalQuery')
from KeyStream select env:getSystemProperty(key) as FunctionOutput 
insert into OutputStream;
```

Comment: Are you using siddhi-runner or wso2 sp? is for what version

Comment: I'm using wso2 stream processor 4.4.0 with siddhi-execution-env 1.1.0 jar and I ran above code in wso2sp editor.

Answer (score 0):

How did you export the variables inside the WSO2 container. Are they System variables or Env variables.
Can you try echoing the said variables inside the container to check whether the variable are correctly populated.
Assuming you are trying out on bare-metal docker, you can use [docker-exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) and echoing the variables.

Comment: I am able to echo them but how can i use them in siddhi script. 
for example i want to declare a url as environment variable and use it inside script how can i do it

Comment: i tried using it like this receiver.url='${customer}' but it didn't work out. should i use different way ?

Comment: Using as '${customer}' was introduced with Siddhi Tooling 5.1.0-m2[1] release. Hence, it is not available in WSO2 Stream Processor 4.4.0.

You can use env:getEnvironmentProperty() as shown in [2] for your usecase with WSO2 Stream Processor 4.4.0


[1]https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/download/
[2] https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-execution-env/api/2.0.0/#getenvironmentproperty-function

Comment: I am able to log the value using env:getSystemProperty(). but how can i assign this value to receiver.url. 
if my RECEIVED_URL is environment variable
'@source(type='http', receiver.url='RECEIVED_URL', @map())' something like this. how can i achieve this in wso2sp4.4.0?

Comment: You can use refs to configure the source in deployment.yml and then use the ref name in the Siddhi app. Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP440/Collecting+Events

for your case the deployment config would look like
siddhi:
 
  refs:
    -
      ref:
        name: 'http-test-source'
        type: 'http'
        properties:
          receiver.url: ${customer}

and the Siddhi source would look like
@Source(ref='http-test-source', basic.auth.enabled='false', @map(type='json'))
define stream SweetProductionStream (name string, amount double);

Comment: Thank you Chiran Fernando Its working, But i need to build the image after making changes in deployment.yml file. If i try to change the deployment.yml file inside the container and restart it,its showing some startup issue.

Comment: You cannot update the deployment.yml during container runtime because container's entry point is set to run Siddhi Runner.
What you can do is to update the deployment.yml locally and mount the deployment.yml to the container's conf directory.